# Suppose I have this HTML code...how do I bold the text inside onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="" onclick="runstuff();return false;">Item</a>
```

After executing runstuff(), I want to use JQuery to make Item **bold**.
Will I need an "id"? What about "self"?

Answer (score 6):

With jQuery, you ought to bind to an attribute or class on the link itself. For instance:

```
<a href="foo.html" class="makeBold">Click Me</a>
```

```
$("a.makeBold").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
});
```

Of course, that's a CSS solution. You can allso wrap the element in `<b>` or `<strong>` tags:

```
$("a.makeBold").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).wrap("<strong>");
});
```

Comment: It'd also be a good idea to specify a specific set of links by scoping the CSS selectors (ie: `#boldlinks a` or what have you).

Comment: You forgot to call runstuff()! +1 though

Comment: @elwyn: He didn't forget. He simply didn't reference `runstuff()` as `runstuff()` It was defined as the handler functions sent to the `click` event handler. Does the same thing, but you don't need to name the function if you don't want. =D

Answer (score 1):

The A you clicked will be 'this' in your example, so just define runstuff:

```
function runstuff() {
    jQuery(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would bolden the text before or after runstuff() ran, but I would expect this would work:

```
$('a[onclick^=runstuff]').click(function(){
      $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
});
```

Perhaps you could ensure it would run after runstuff() by using jQuery to change the onclick attribute? Something like

```
$('a[onclick^=runstuff]').attrib('onclick','runstuff();boldtext();return true;');
```

Then you'd have to define boldtext()

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify your HTML into:

```
<a href="#" onclick="runstuff(this);return false;">Item</a>
```

And, you can have the script like:

```
function runstuff(link) {
    jQuery(link).css("font-weight", "bold");
}
```